# Lotus Domino mail routing and separation

Tags: email, ibm-domino, lotus-notes

Mail Separation – Goal is to allow mail separation between different OUs while minimizing the number of servers required.
a)  Users of the same OU can email back and forth.
b)  Member of different OUs cannot receive emails from other OUs
c)  When User sends mail from each sub OU, they should only be able to see/use addresses corresponding to that sub OU
d) May need a large number of OUs.

EXAMPLE:

```
            John Doe/OUb/CORP/O   = john.doe@ouB.corp.o.com      Mailfile  =  data\WEB\b\mail\jdoeB.nsf
            John Doe/OUc/CORP/O   = john.doe@ouC.corp.o.com       Mailfile  =  data\WEB\c\mail\jdoeC.nsf
             Bill Smith/OUb/CORP/O   = bill.smith@ouB.corp.o.com     Mailfile  =  data\WEB\b\mail\bsmithB.nsf
            Bill Smith/OUc/CORP/O   = bill.smith@ouC.corp.o.com      Mailfile  =  data\WEB\c\mail\bsmithC.nsf

            Bill Smith/OUc/CORP/O can email John Doe/OUc/CORP/O  but not John Doe/OUb/CORP/O
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this with Extended Acl. Read [this article](https://searchdomino.techtarget.com/tip/Controlling-access-to-the-Domino-Directory-with-Extended-ACL) on how to start. You can also read the admin help on this topic